# Stack Exchange Data Dump — OwnerDisplayName and LastEditorDisplayName

Tags: support, data-dump

I'm using the [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and am trying to have posts along with the creators of the posts. I would like to put text like "created on [date] by [user]". In most cases, the fields `OwnerDisplayName` and `LastEditorDisplayName` are null.

Is this intentional? If so, why is the name only available in some cases?

Also, [the readme](https://ia600107.us.archive.org/27/items/stackexchange/readme.txt) that shows which fields are available is missing `OwnerDisplayName`. I found it from the post *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678)*.

Comment: Can you give an example for one of the posts you're interested in which still has the post and user available on the network? If it's not longer available on the network or the user account is no longer available, that may have something to do with it.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. For example in cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com, out of 457 posts in the most recent dump, only 18 have `OwnerDisplayName`, and of those, 14 are by the same user. A [newer post I found](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/308) with the author still listed does not have either of the name attributes.

Comment: Don't use those fields, use the actual fields (OwnerUserId and LastEditorUserId) and join with Users to read their names. Any other way won't be reliable.

Answer (score 5):

`OwnerDisplayName` and `LastEditorDisplayName` are [de-normalized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90412). They may not reliably contain data. If they do, it may not be updated when the name changes. It is [advised to not rely on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175511/trouble-with-fetching-data/175517#comment526537_175517).

Comment: Got it, thank you. Do you know why it's available in some cases? Also, I want to attribute authors for their posts. Is it recommended I reference `OwnerUserId` with Users?

Comment: @busterroni owerdisplayname gets set when a user deletes their profile. So you'll find either a OwnerUserId pointing to a record in the Users table or a non-null value in OwnerDisplayName. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90411/whats-the-point-of-ownerdisplayname-lasteditordisplayname-if-its-not-even-corr/353067#353067. There might be cases (I think of SE staff anonymizing posts) where both fields end-up empty.

Comment: @rene got it, thanks. I think the readme should be updated to include the missing field anyway.

Comment: @busterroni given that keeping the [readme up-to-date is a hassle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302212/please-update-the-readme-txt-in-the-data-dump), you better refer to the [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Comment: @rene that's what I'm now referring to, but it would be good if someone updated the readme, or linked to that post from it